# Um método parando o loop de outro método

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, condição

Eu tenho quatros objetos (já instanciados) triangulo, quadrado, circulo e um ultimo picture, responsável por invocar ambos os métodos de cada classe dos respectivos objetos, afim de desenhar uma casa, um sol, uma chaminé, uma janela e um telhado, e colocá-los de forma ordenada para dar vida a imagem.

Antes que esqueça de mencionar, para fins didáticos, meu professor está utilizando o `blueJ` - segundo ele a ferramenta proporciona melhor entendimento na IOO. Até aqui ta tudo funcionando perfeitamente.

Embora estamos iniciando na orientação a objetos, já passamos por disciplinas de linguagens primitivas, então podem deduzir que ainda pouco sei sobre o assunto.

As minhas dificuldades consistem:

1. Preciso chamar um método "`turnOnFireplace`" como o nome já diz acender a chaminé, fazendo com que saia fumaças da chaminé na animação;
2. Criar outro método "turnOffFireplace" para apagar a chaminé, fazendo com que pare de sair fumaça.

O que eu fiz:

Pensei em criar uma variável do tipo booleana para representar o estado da chaminé (acesa/apagada), faço um laço `do-while` para criar o circulo(representando a fumaça), faço ele se mover como se estivesse saindo da chaminé, sumir e retornar o ponto de partida, fazendo tudo novamente até ser invocado o método `turnOffFireplace` para alterar o valor da variável de on para false dando um "*break*" no laço. é parando a execução da animação, entretanto quando eu invoco o 'turnOffFireplace' o método, pelo qual, deveria altera o valor da variável on para false, e parar loop, quebrando-o, isso não acontece... o loop continua.

Vou representar melhor com o código a seguir.

```
 public void turnOnFireplace()
{
    smoke = new Circle();

    on = true;

    do
    {
        smoke.changeColor("black");
        smoke.slowMoveVertical(100);
        smoke.makeInvisible();
        smoke.move(-100);
    }while(on = true);
}
public void turnOffFireplace()
{   
    on = false;
}
```

A variável a qual mencionei foi declarada no inicio da classe `Picture`.

O que acontece é que o loop não para. Tentei outras variações desta lógica mas não resolveu. Como resolver isso?

Comment: Seria só um erro de digitação? `while(on == true);`. Por isso que é melhor fazer o certo: `while(on);`.

Comment: Você poderia ser um pouco mais claro, pois o se eu colocar mudar o valor da variável de true pra false... se é que eu entendi ele vai parar. no primeiro loop certo?

Comment: Você poderia ser mais claro na sua pergunta? Eu estou tendo que imaginar coisas já que não tem toda informação do funcionamento deste mecanismo. Você está fazendo com que cada passagem pelo laço o variável passe ser `true`, então ela o laço nunca termina. Se você apenar usar a variável sem ficar atribuindo uma valor sem sentido nela, deve funcionar. Se não funcionar tem problemas em outros lugares que não dá para perceber com o código postado.

Comment: Ok! o método turnOnFireplace sera responsável por iniciar o laço, como este método a variável on já ta recebendo true, o laço vai iniciar, certo? Então, já no metodo turnOffFireplace modifica a variável on para false, no meu raciocínio uma vez que, o on teve seu valor alterado, o laço é quebrado.

Comment: O problema inicial é outro. Outro problema que pode estar acontecendo é que `turnOffFireplace()` nunca está sendo chamado. Se está, sua pergunta deveria mostrar isto.

Comment: A tá, falha nossa, o bluej faz isso de forma gráfica, no projeto, eu crio os objetos, escrevo o algoritmo em cada um, e crio um objeto que vai iniciar digamos "o programa" ao passo que, em um menu pop-up abre e nele eu escolhe os métodos que vou chamar. tipo como se eu simula-se as ações do projeto

Comment: Apenas uma sugestão, em `turnOnFireplace()` vc poderia passar a quantia de lenhas a queimas com esse número faça um `for` para ele gerar as 'bolinhas de fumaça' após isso chame `turnOffFireplace()`. Uma hora o fogo acaba naturalmente xD haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo pouco do código que foi colocado não dá para afirmar se tem um erro de engenharia de toda a classe. Vou considerar que tem alguma coisa que altere o estado da variável `on` para `false` em algum momento. Isto provavelmente se dará chamando o método `turnOffFireplace()`. Se isto ocorre de forma concomitante ou não é uma questão que não dá para saber pelo exposto no código. Se o método não é chamado para mudar o estado da variável `on` em outra *thread*, de forma segura espero eu, então a única forma de mudar o estado da variável dentro do laço é chamando o método direta ou indiretamente.

Diretamente não está sendo chamado, isto dá para ver. Acho pouco provável que esteja sendo chamado indiretamente. Todos os métodos chamados não parecem ser adequados para chamar `turnOffFireplace()`, afinal são métodos que só deveriam traçar um círculo.

Se não resolver isto não tem solução. Quando deve chamar eu não sei, não há nada na pergunta que deixe isto claro. Mesmo que o BlueJ faça isso, não está claro como.

Uma alternativa é ter um sistema de eventos controlando o estado da variável e a exibição da fumaça deva ocorrer por evento controlado pelo laço principal no jogo. Mas aí é um trabalho de engenharia que vai além do escopo da pergunta.

## Erro de digitação

Existe um outro problema sério no código e mesmo que resolva essa questão de engenharia, ainda não vai funcionar. O código:

```
}while(on = true);
```

está errado, o que está fazendo aí é atribuir o valor `true` para a variável `on`, portando o `while` será sempre verdadeiro, mesmo que o valor de `on` tenha sido mudado em outro lugar, ficará errado todas as vezes que passar pelo laço. Esta linha deveria ser:

```
} while (on);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/WhileTrue.java).

Se o BlueJ se vira para alterar o estado da variável de alguma forma, então isto deve resolver o problema.

Por isto é que eu digo que é péssimo usar `variavel == true`. Tem gente que defende que isto é mais legível. Pra mim é menos legível e induz erros de digitação, como o ocorrido.